# Why we cannot define primary key ourself in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, primary-key

The `_id` field is reserved for **primary key** in `mongodb`. But why `mongodb` is designed like this? And can I define the primary key myself?

Comment: Isn't `_id` the only field that's guaranteed to be present on every record?  If anything else isn't present it wouldn't make for a very good key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own primary key for your collection. Note that MongoDB drivers automatically generate unique _id values; however, you can override this _id value:

eg. db.yourcollection.insert({_id:"myuniquevalueN",a:1,b:1})

You can also create secondary indexes that enforce uniqueness. Refer below:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

I'm not sure if I understand the why part of your question. As you mention _id is a primary key and serves the point of ensuring uniqueness of a document within a collection, and a means of retrieving documents by a unique id. It's purpose is no different from primary keys in other databases. Why is it pre-defined? It's partly due to the fact that MongoDB assigns a unique object Id value for you automatically if you don't specify one for that purpose. Having a standard _id field simplifies the implementation.

Comment: I think question was: "How can I define a custom field as a primary key". Or, "Why _id is the fixed name of the primary key". 
The main point being that in any other DB we can use any field/column or combination/part of them to define the primary key.

Answer (score 2):

An _id needs to be unique. As mongodb nodes can be geographically distributed, the aim is to minimize any potential chances of collisions.

Comment: The _id field has nothing to do with geographic distribution. It's purpose is no different from primary keys in other systems. Geographic distribution is handled by replica sets which provides HA dealing with things like network partitions. Some people use geotags with sharding to route queries to specific locations/DC, but this has nothing to do with the _id field.